# How to save large object with gson in a json file?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am retrieving an XML response from a server that is over 50+ Mbs.
Here I am using retrofit and with the help of `@Streaming` annotation I am saving this response directly to the file, so I can overcome the `Out Of Memory Exception`.
So far everything looks good here no memory problem.
Now I am parsing this XML file when completely downloaded to Pojo Class Object according to data using `SAX XML Parser`, now you can imagine if the file is 50+ Mbs then how big is this Object.
After converting this XML to Pojo Class Object, now I am passing this object to `Gson` so he can convert this `Object` to `JSON` for me and after this, I am taking this `JSON` string and save it to a separate file.
Now again, `Gson` is going to do all this in memory, now here phones got exhausted, tired and throw `Out Of Memory Exception` and that's correct because, as if we looked this as memory consumption point of view 
First, he tries to convert XML to Pojo Classes, 
Then transfer this response to `Gson` for converting to `JSON` and during this conversation he puts all this data in memory after this pass to me then I pass this to file writing object for storing..etc
Which really becomes huge at this point.
So, My Question
Is there any way I can ask `Gson` to write his `JSON` response directly to a file instead of saving it to memory?

Comment: Have you looked into how Gson deals with streams, e.g., `JsonWriter`? Read XML stream, convert each element and attribute and write each converted element to JSON stream directly. Memory foot-print would be as small as possible. I'd say that you even don't need to use Gson for it, since there are plenty JSON writers in Java (if I'm not mistaken, there is a Android built-in too).

Comment: In short, I don't believe you have to map your data to DTO representation at all...

Comment: @fluffy well I haven't yet read about this `JsonWriter` but will do it later also I know there are built-in JSON writers available but because of the ease of `Gson`, I like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, look like this is working for me but it's slower.
Any better solution than this is welcome.

```
val xmlParser = XmlParser()   // Custom Class for XML Conversion
xmlParser.parseXml(xmlFile)
val writer = FileWriter(jsonFile) // Simple file Object contaning path to the saved location
val data = GsonBuilder()
             .setPrettyPrinting()
             .create()
             .toJson(xmlParser.data, writer)
writer.close()
```

---

Ok, here I have found a better solution than above which is 8x faster than the previous one.
In this, all are the same just change and pass the `BufferedWriter` object to the `toJson` fun call instead of simple `FileWriter`.
e.g: `val writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(jsonFile))`